# Rails 4 How to use render layout option in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Just messing around with rails layouts.  Going through the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) 
2.2.11.2 The :layout Option

Created a simple layout called two_column_landing and put it in the layouts directory under app/views.

Then modified my view to render the layout:

```
<h1>Ca#tcl</h1>
  <p>Find me in app/views/ca/tcl.html.erb</p>

  <%= render layout: "two_column_landing" %>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
You invoked render but did not give any of :partial, :template, :inline, :file or :text option.
```

I know this is probably not a great thing to be doing as a habit in production code but I'm just figuring out how to do what I want.  Any ideas why this isn't working?  Is it not a feature of rails 4?

Comment: did you put that file 'two_column_landing.html.erb' inside app/views/layouts/ folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might keep reading. There are many ways layout can be used.  If you want to call a specific layout for a given action, you should do that in a your controller, not in your view.  If you need to call in a view, to give a layout for a partial, then the syntax is different, you call the partial first and then the layout.

```
<%= render "comments", layout: "two_column_landing" %>
```

If you just want you 2 column view to render in a particular controller then at the top of the controller before any method definitions call, under the class name

```
layout "two_column_landing"
```

If you want to only call this layout for a specific action in the controller you can do it in the method render

```
   def index
     @people = Person.all
     render layout: "multi-column"
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this and working well for rails 4

```
def index
    @people = Person.all
    render :layout => "my-layout-name"
end
```